# stop visual studio's linker from looking for python39_d.lib in debug mode

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, linker

I don't really know why the linker will sometimes choose to automatically search for libraries suffixed with 'd' or '_d' when I run in debug mode. I am trying out calling python modules from C++ in Windows. I create a blank C++ project in Visual Studio 2022 and write thr following code:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello world";
}
```

I have Anaconda3 installed on my computer and `Python.h` lives in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include` so I add it to my include path. The output of my debug build is `LNK1104   cannot open file python39_d.lib`. Oops! I must have forgotten to point the linker to the static lib from the python API. But wait! All that I find in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\libs` is `python39.lib`. Anaconda forgot to ship me my `python39_d.lib` file which for some reason is automatically linked to. The stupid work around is to copy it and rename the copy so that it matches what the linker expects, but I would rather just link to the non-debug library.

But how? Is it a `#pragma` inside of `Python.h` causing this? It's a cruel trick for a python distro to ship an API that can't work without a workaround. Or is it some obscure Visual Studio setting I don't know about?

Comment: It certainly could be a `#pragma comment (lib ...)` inside of `Python.h`, I suggest you take a look. You could also look at the Project Properties/Linker/All Options setting to see if the library is getting included some other way.

Comment: There are no `pragmas` in Python.h, but it does include a lot of files. I think it would be pretty bad practice to hide something like that---I assume the python dev team wouldn't be so silly.

Comment: ...and there is nothing in the linker options that I can see---never is in cases where I hit this issue. As I said in the OP, blank project.

Comment: AFAIK `#pragma` is the only possibility then, it must be there somewhere.

Comment: I checked a few likely candidates (e.g. compile.h, pymacro.h, etc.). No sign of any `#pragma`s at all. In fact, I would be surprised if there are any. Every file uses the `#ifndef...` pattern instead of `#pragma once` and has `#ifdef __cplusplus exertn "C"...` as well. It's really a C api, not a C++ api.

Comment: you can't mix debug and release libraries (unless you're very careful) so the fact that the debug library is linked automatically is a good thing, you'll need to get a debug build of python

Comment: @AlanBirtles so far I haven't had any issues, but I do anticipate having some with the workaround I suggest. Different ABIs = hell. I'm sure I can find python39_d.lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is by design:
In `pyconfig.h`

```
ifdef MS_COREDLL
#       if !defined(Py_BUILD_CORE) && !defined(Py_BUILD_CORE_BUILTIN)
                /* not building the core - must be an ext */
#               if defined(_MSC_VER)
                        /* So MSVC users need not specify the .lib
                        file in their Makefile (other compilers are
                        generally taken care of by distutils.) */
#                       if defined(_DEBUG)
#                               pragma comment(lib,"python39_d.lib")
```